# How to stop float:left div from being covered up by following div?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have the following code:

```
<div>
    <div onmouseover="this.style.color='red'" 
         onmouseout="this.style.color='blue'" 
         style="float:left">
        a
        <br/>
        b
        <br/>
        c
    </div>
    <div onmouseover="this.style.color='red'" 
         onmouseout="this.style.color='blue'" 
         style="position:relative;">
        Testing, one two three...
    </div>
</div>
```

The first div pushes the text in the second div to the right, but not the second div itself, so the `a` in the first inner div will be covered up by the `T` in the second inner div, and hovering over the `a` will not trigger the onmouseover.

This is a pretty simplified example, but how do I get this sort of layout, preserving the `position:relative` of the second div and not adding any margins to it, since the first div may or may not be displayed?  It seems strange that the second div will cover up the first.

Comment: With the HTML/styles you listed here, those elements shouldn't have overlapping text. Are you sure this is the whole sample that replicates the problem? Can you provide more code for context, including all applied styles? In which browsers/versions are you having the problem?

Comment: the text isn't overlapping, but if you try this code out, you'll see the onmouseover event isn't working for the `a`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understood you correctly.. Put `float: left;` to the second div as well.